# Laravel livewire component not refreshing after saving model

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I'm stuck on what I feel like should be easy, but it's just not working. I'm saving a record to the database for the collection that's displayed as a list on the page. So after saving that record, I want to update the page to show the updated list, including the new record, automatically.

The blade component is pretty straight forward foreach loop over the collection. I've removed some of the code for simplicity, but I'm aware that it all must be in a single div element:

```
<div>
    @foreach ($statements as $statement)
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2" wire:key="statement-{{ $statement->id }}">
                ...other stuff.
            </div>
        @endforeach
</div>
```

and in my Livewire component I'm doing this currently, which is not working:

```
class VendorStatement extends Component
{
    public Location $location;
    public Statement $statement;
    public $statements;

    protected $listeners = [
        'fileUploaded'      => 'save',
        'refreshComponent'  => '$refresh',
    ];


    public function mount(Location $location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->refreshStatements();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.locations.statements');
    }

    public function refreshStatements()
    {
        $this->statements = $this->location->statements;
        $this->render();
    }

    public function save($uploadedFile)
    {
        if ($path = Storage::disk('s3')->put(env('APP_ENV') . '/statements/' . $uploadedFile[1], file_get_contents($uploadedFile[0]))) {
            $this->statement = new Statement([
                'location_id'   => $this->location->id,
                'file_name'     => $uploadedFile[1],
                'path'          => $path,
                'uploaded_by'   => Auth::user()->id,
            ]);

            $this->statement->save();
        }

        StatementUploadedEvent::dispatch($this->statement);
        $this->refreshStatements();
    }
}
```

**Things I've Tried:**

I've tried using `$this->emit('refreshComponent');` after the save instead of calling the `refreshStatements` method.

I've tried just setting the value of `$this->statements` again as well.

Not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Well, seems like you passing $location from outside of component? There was no query anywhere with can be refreshed and when component was rerendering had same data from outside of component.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by modifying my code like so:

```
public function render()
    {
        $this->refreshStatements();
        return view('livewire.locations.statements');
    }

    public function refreshStatements()
    {
        $this->statements = $this->location->statements;
    }
```

I still don't understand why this wouldn't work the way I had it configured, but at least it works.